# Program to compare binary files

Tags: file-comparison, binary-files

I'm looking for a freeware program that compares two binary files with each other, and can do the following things:

1. Give a percentage of similarity
2. Hash the files (give a few basic, as well as fuzzy hashes, md5, sh1/sh2, etc etc)
3. Compare more then 2 programs with each other, and list them in some sort of database

If you know a program like this, please do post.

Comment: The title "Compare programs" is misleading, I would use "Comparison software" or "Comparison apps"

Answer (score 1):

given your requirements, i would advise writing a perl or python script. both languages will have adequate library support to enable you to perform whatever operations you wish on the file data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if there is an existing program that does all you want - without some level of programming effort.

The [Gnu diffutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) can do some of that and there is a comparison of some tools at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)